# Error Handling and auto-Fetching in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I am very new to react and trying to make a note-keeping application. I am using Firebase Realtime Database for storing data. So, until now, the only functionality is that the user can only store their note by clicking "Add Note" Btn.
Here is the code for saving Notes in the Database:

```js
import reducerStore from '../../store/Reducer';
import './Header.css';

export default function Header() {
  const { state, dispatch } = reducerStore();

  const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'title', value: event.target.value });
  };
  const noteChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'note', value: event.target.value });
  };

  const submitHandler = async () => {
    // console.log(state);
    const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: state.title, note: state.note }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      dispatch({ type: 'error', value: 'something went wrong' });
      return;
    }

    // console.log(response);
    dispatch({ type: 'reset' });
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {console.log('inside header component:', state)}
      <div className='title'>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='title'
          id='title'
          placeholder='Name Title'
          onChange={titleChangeHandler}
          value={state.title}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='notes-para'>
        <textarea
          type='text'
          name='note'
          id='note'
          size={200}
          placeholder='write your note here'
          value={state.note}
          onChange={noteChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='header-btn'>
        <button onClick={submitHandler}>Add Note</button>
      </div>
      {state.error ? <p>{state.error}</p> : ''}
    </div>
  );
}
```

First there is a quick Doubt:

- I am using useReducer hook for managing state. I tried to use UseState also. on both hook component re-render on every key stroke.
- Then I used onBlur event instead of onChange. then there its shows warning in console. **warning:** You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
- For stop re-rendering " useRef " Hook is used. but is it okay to clear the form by manually changing *ref.current*  value on clicking btn?

so Now first see the Error Problem:

- so here in the above code, error is working fine. I only want the error msg will disappear after 5 second.

for this what I had tried is this:  This is reducer code.

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';

// reducer function
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'title') {
    return {
      title: action.value,
      note: state.note,
      error: state.error,
    };
  } else if (action.type === 'note') {
    return {
      title: state.title,
      note: action.value,
      error: state.error,
    };
  } else if (action.type === 'reset') {
    return {
      title: '',
      note: '',
      error: null,
    };
  } else if (action.type === 'error') {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      return { title: '', note: '', error: action.value };
    },5000)
    return initialState;
  } else {
    return initialState;
  }
};

// define intital state
const initialState = { title: '', note: '', error: null };

const reducerStore = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return { state, dispatch };
};

export default reducerStore;
```

its not working.

2. second problem is auto fetching when new note is added in database.

here is that code:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import reducerStore from './store/Reducer';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/Navbar/NavBar';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Card from './components/Card/Card';

function App() {
  const { state } = reducerStore();

  // fetch data from firebase whenever new note is added.
  useEffect(() => {
    const autoFetch = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    };
    autoFetch();
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <NavBar />
      <Header />
      <Card />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am adding state as an dependencies, so that whenever state change, useEffect will run. but its not working.

- what I think is we need to call this autoFetch function inside submitHandler btn after fetch POST operation.

please also tell me if this is the best practice for writing code or not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your questions and issues one by one:

1. **Use of `useReducer` vs. `useState`:** The choice between `useReducer` and `useState` depends on your application's complexity and how you want to manage state. If you're experiencing too many re-renders with `useState`, it might be because you're using a single state variable for multiple fields. In such cases, `useReducer` can be a good choice to manage separate pieces of state.
2. **`onChange` vs. `onBlur`:** The warning you're getting about not providing an `onChange` handler when using `value` is because React expects an event handler to update the state when the input changes. Using `onBlur` can work but is not as responsive as `onChange`. You should handle `onChange` and update the state as the user types.
3. **Using `useRef` to stop re-rendering:** Using `useRef` to manually clear the form by changing `ref.current` value on clicking a button is a valid approach if you want to control when the form is cleared. It can help avoid unnecessary re-renders caused by state changes.
4. **Clearing Error Message:** In your reducer, the `setTimeout` is not correctly updating the state. You should return the new state inside the `setTimeout` callback like this:

   ```js
   } else if (action.type === 'error') {
     setTimeout(() => {
       dispatch({ type: 'reset' }); // Clear the error after 5 seconds
     }, 5000);
     return { ...state, error: action.value };
   }
   ```
5. **Auto Fetching Data:** In your `useEffect` for auto-fetching data, it's not working as expected because you're using `state` as a dependency. When you dispatch an action to update `state` inside `submitHandler`, it doesn't trigger the effect. To fix this, you can remove `state` as a dependency and fetch data after a successful POST operation inside `submitHandler`:

   ```js
   const submitHandler = async () => {
     const response = await fetch('https://notes-keeper-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/notes.json', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({ title: state.title, note: state.note }),
     });

     if (!response.ok) {
       dispatch({ type: 'error', value: 'something went wrong' });
       return;
     }

     // Fetch data here after successful POST
     autoFetch();
     dispatch({ type: 'reset' });
   };
   ```

   This way, you ensure that the data is fetched after a new note is added.

As for best practices, React code can vary depending on the project and its requirements. What you've shared seems reasonable for a simple note-keeping app. However, as your app grows in complexity, you might consider using a state management library like Redux to handle global state more efficiently. Additionally, consider organizing your code into separate components and files to improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: Hi thanks for solving my doubts. There is problem in your code, error handling inside setTimeout function. its showing dispatch is not define.